# Is NSURLConnectionDataDelegate's didReceiveData method throttled?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, chunked-encoding, nsurlconnectiondelegate

The [docs for the `connection:didReceiveData` delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connection:didReceiveData:) of `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` say that the `didReceiveData` message will be sent “as a connection loads data incrementally.”

Surely, this can't mean that it `didReceiveData` will be sent for each and every byte that comes over the wire. Does anyone know what algorithm is used to throttle `didReceiveData` messages?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience that callback is invoked any time the connection receives another data packet from the network. Packet size can vary depending on network conditions but is typically a from 1 to several kB. You won't get that callback for every byte, but for large transfers you may get a lot of them.